# Обновление цен opencart товаров с XML файла

Tags: opencart, плагин

Есть ссылка на XML файл (на сторонний сайт). Там мы имеем [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно обновить цены и остаток товара в нашей БД. В этом файле есть id - это название модели и для нее есть retail_price(цена) и stock(остаток). Вот эти данные мне нужно обновить в моей БД.

Возможно есть для этих целей уже готовое решение(плагин)?
Буду весьма благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Для поиска плагинов к движку обратитесь на форум движка. На stackoverflow мы решаем другие вопросы.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что для поиска плагинов к движку необходимо обращаться на форум этого движка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое решается и без плагина. Достаточно написать небольшое vqmod-расширение. Или, если вы не планируете обновление системы, закодить в шаблон админки. 
В двух словах, вам надо принять xml, из него "замассивить" код товара и цену на уровне "ключ-значение". Далее дописать модель, ибо в опенкарте, к сожалению, нет метода массовой обработки информации о товарах. В общих чертах.
А плагин, извините, ищите сами.